# How do I set hibernate.jdbc.batch_size on StatelessSession basis?

Tags: hibernate

Is there a way to set `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` on a specific session?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this would be very useful (use a high value only for batch processings), but I think this is not possible as the setting is a Configuration property. You will need a new `SessionFactory`.